# Generating onclick text at the bottom of my SVG, modifying 'selected' colour

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, raphael

With the aid of a tutorial, I've built a map of five regions of England in SVG. I've used Raphael to work with it a little. Most of it seems to be turning out alright so far:
http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/EjExeO
I'm trying to add two more features and am just not sure how to do it. Are you able to help, please?

I'd like to: Set up the effect of the regions turning red upon clicking so that only the most recently clicked region is coloured. Can you help explain what I'm supposed to do to make this shift from region to region? At the moment, a region gets clicked and stays highlighted.

I'd like to figure out how to add more text to the bottom of the canvas. It may mean adding more information to my JSON but I'm hoping that I can add the text - about two paragraphs with a hyperlink - as a string.

Can you please let me know if you have thoughts about ways that I can do the two things outlined above?

Thank you,
Matt

The full code is [on Codepen](http://codepen.io/msummers40/pen/EjExeO). What I've added below is a representative sample of the code.

```
var regions = [
{'title':"northeast_england", 'path' : "M219.02,6.876l-0.079,0.05l-0.482,0.371L218.23,7.47l-0.858,0.346h-0.008l-0.307,0.26l-0.779,0.666 l-0.104,0.278l-0.005,0.019l0.056,0.481l0.116,0.846l0.048,0.395l-0.344,1.05l-0.052-0.007v0.007l-0.635-0.081l-0.375,0.167 l-0.148,0.061v0.006l-0.1,0.328l0.178,0.338l-0.104,0.353h-0.006l-0.32,0.179l-0.056,0.031l-0.161,0.729h-0.006v0.012l-0.271,0.117 l-0.08,0.031l-0.031-0.019l-0.043,0.019l-0.327-0.167l-0.147-0.079l-0.117-0.007h-0.021l-0.216-0.006l-0.419,0.252l-0.009,0.007 l-0.004,0.302v0.605l-0.117,0.292l-0.037,0.11h-0.006v0.006h-0.025l-0.37,0.056l-0.536,0.079l-0.562,0.372l0.017,0.165l0.033,0.187 l0.481,0.788l0.023,0.038l0.008,0.013l-0.988,0.425l-0.594,0.637l-0.011,0.03l-0.187,0.637l-0.068,0.062l-0.801,0.747l-0.409,0.617 l0.062,0.414l0.068,0.414l-0.012,0.012l-0.203,0.228h-0.008l-0.123,0.05l-0.006,0.005l-0.377,0.136l-0.073,0.074l-0.13,0.143 l-0.401,0.426l-0.081,0.08l-0.055,0.055l-0.116,0.136l-0.05,0.364l0.646,0.191l0.025,0.119l0.05,0.153l-0.265,0.148l-0.26,0.155 l-0.155-0.006l-0.005,0.006l-0.309-0.006l-0.648-0.365l-0.624,0.142l-0.363,0.087l-......LOTS MORE COORDINATES...."},

THERE ARE SEVERAL OTHER SVG REGIONS/SHAPES IN THE CODEPEN LINK


var MAP_WIDTH  = 600;
var MAP_HEIGHT = 600;

var mapContainer = document.getElementById("map");
var map = new Raphael(mapContainer, MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT);
var group = map.set();

var style = {
  fill: "#ddd",
  stroke: "#aaa",
  "stroke-width": 1,
  "stroke-linejoin": "round",
  cursor: "pointer"
};


regions.forEach(function(region){
    group.push(
     map.path(region.path).attr('title', region.title)
   );  
});

group.attr(style);
group.click(function(){
  var slug = this.attr('title');
  var title;
  var fill = this.attr('fill') == 'red' ? '#1f1f1f' : 'red';

  // format the title
  title = slug.split('-')
         .map(function(subString){
            return subString[0].toUpperCase() + subString.substr(1);
          })
          .join(' ')
          .trim();


  // add some color
  this.attr('fill', fill);

  // do something useful
  document.getElementById('title').textContent = title;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the highlight thing, what I would do is have your click function as follows (pseudocode)::

```
on-region-clicked {
   remove class "highlight" from all regions
   add class "highlight" to clicked region 
}
```

Where class "highlight" is:

```
.highlight {
  fill: red;
}
```

I'll leave the actual Raphael code up to you.

Comment: Paul. Any chance you have ideas about how to add an additional line of text below the title? I've clarified the question a little here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235512/svg-raphael-js-json-data-cant-figure-out-how-to-get-description-to-appear